# How Can I update the data in TableView Static Cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I want to update the values of counts, but I am not able to do that..! I tried it, but it is update when I build a code...!

Here is a screenshot of a tableview:

[image: 1]

Here is the code for this,

```
#import "LeftMenuViewController.h"
#import "RKDropdownAlert.h"
#import "HexColors.h"
#import "AppConstanst.h"
#import "GlobalVariables.h"
#import "MyWebservices.h"
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
@import Firebase;
@interface LeftMenuViewController (){
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults;
    GlobalVariables *globalVariables;
    NSArray *numbers;
}
@end

@implementation LeftMenuViewController

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self.slideOutAnimationEnabled = YES;

    return [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"Naaa-LeftMENU");


    self.tableView.tableFooterView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    userDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    globalVariables=[GlobalVariables sharedInstance];
     NSLog(@"Role : %@",[userDefaults objectForKey:@"role"]);
    _user_role.text=[[userDefaults objectForKey:@"role"] uppercaseString];

    _user_nameLabel.text=[userDefaults objectForKey:@"profile_name"];
    _url_label.text=[userDefaults objectForKey:@"baseURL"];

    [_user_profileImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[userDefaults objectForKey:@"profile_pic"]]
                          placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default_pic.png"]];
    _user_profileImage.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor hx_colorWithHexRGBAString:@"#0288D1"] CGColor];

    _user_profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = _user_profileImage.frame.size.height /2;
    _user_profileImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    _user_profileImage.layer.borderWidth = 0;



    NSInteger open =  [globalVariables.OpenCount integerValue];
    NSInteger closed = [globalVariables.ClosedCount integerValue];
    NSInteger trash = [globalVariables.DeletedCount integerValue];
    NSInteger unasigned = [globalVariables.UnassignedCount integerValue];
    NSInteger my_tickets = [globalVariables.MyticketsCount integerValue];

    if(open>999){
        _inbox_countLabel.text=@"999+";
    }else
        _inbox_countLabel.text=@(open).stringValue;
    if(closed>999){
        _closed_countLabel.text=@"999+";
    }else
        _closed_countLabel.text=@(closed).stringValue;
    if(trash>999){
        _trash_countLabel.text=@"999+";
    }else
        _trash_countLabel.text=@(trash).stringValue;
    if(unasigned>999){
        _unassigned_countLabel.text=@"999+";
    }else
        _unassigned_countLabel.text=@(unasigned).stringValue;
    if(my_tickets>999){
        _myTickets_countLabel.text=@"999+";
    }else
        _myTickets_countLabel.text=@(my_tickets).stringValue;

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                             bundle: nil];

    // UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIViewController *vc ;

    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
        case 1:
            vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"CreateTicket"];
            break;

        case 2:
            [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
            break;
        case 3:
            vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"InboxID"];
            break;
        case 4:
            vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"MyTicketsID"];
            break;
        case 5:
            vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"UnassignedTicketsID"];
            break;
        case 6:
            vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"ClosedTicketsID"];
            break;

        case 7:
            vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"TrashTicketsID"];
            break;

        case 8:
            vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"ClientListID"];
            break;

        case 10:
            vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"AboutVCID"];
            break;


        case 11:

            [self wipeDataInLogout];
            //[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
            //[[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

            [RKDropdownAlert title:@"Faveo Helpdesk" message:@"You've logged out, successfully." backgroundColor:[UIColor hx_colorWithHexRGBAString:SUCCESS_COLOR] textColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"Login"];
            // (vc.view.window!.rootViewController?).dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil);
            break;


        default:
            break;
    }

    [[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance] popToRootAndSwitchToViewController:vc
                                                             withSlideOutAnimation:self.slideOutAnimationEnabled
                                                                     andCompletion:nil];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (indexPath.row == 9) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return [super tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

}

-(void)wipeDataInLogout{

    [self sendDeviceToken];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    // get documents path
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    // get the path to our Data/plist file
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"faveoData.plist"];
    NSError *error;
    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:plistPath error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error while removing the plist %@", error.localizedDescription);
        //TODO: Handle/Log error
    }

    NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (NSHTTPCookie *each in cookieStorage.cookies) {
        [cookieStorage deleteCookie:each];
    }

}

-(void)sendDeviceToken{

   // NSUserDefaults *userDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@fcmtoken?user_id=%@&fcm_token=%s&os=%@",[userDefaults objectForKey:@"companyURL"],[userDefaults objectForKey:@"user_id"],"0",@"ios"];
    MyWebservices *webservices=[MyWebservices sharedInstance];
    [webservices httpResponsePOST:url parameter:@"" callbackHandler:^(NSError *error,id json,NSString* msg){
        if (error || [msg containsString:@"Error"]) {
            if (msg) {

                // [utils showAlertWithMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error-%@",msg] sendViewController:self];
                NSLog(@"Thread-postAPNS-toserver-error == %@",error.localizedDescription);
            }else if(error)  {
                //                [utils showAlertWithMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error-%@",error.localizedDescription] sendViewController:self];
                NSLog(@"Thread-postAPNS-toserver-error == %@",error.localizedDescription);
            }
            return ;
        }
        if (json) {

            NSLog(@"Thread-sendAPNS-token-json-%@",json);
        }

    }];
}

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // rows in section 0 should not be selectable
    // if ( indexPath.section == 0 ) return nil;

    // first 3 rows in any section should not be selectable
    if ( (indexPath.row ==0) || (indexPath.row==2) ) return nil;

    // By default, allow row to be selected
    return indexPath;
}


@end
```

Comment: Write those inside `CellForRowAtIndexPath` rather than `ViewWillAppear`

Comment: You cannot update a static cell hence the title `Static`. If you want dynamic data, why not use a dynamic cell?

Comment: thats great idea....! Let me check ..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do one thing, in viewDidLoad method add method like

```
[self update];
```

then, add that code in this method.

```
-(void)update{


    userDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    globalVariables=[GlobalVariables sharedInstance];
    NSLog(@"Role : %@",[userDefaults objectForKey:@"role"]);
    _user_role.text=[[userDefaults objectForKey:@"role"] uppercaseString];

    _user_nameLabel.text=[userDefaults objectForKey:@"profile_name"];
    _url_label.text=[userDefaults objectForKey:@"baseURL"];

    [_user_profileImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[userDefaults objectForKey:@"profile_pic"]]
                          placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default_pic.png"]];
    _user_profileImage.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor hx_colorWithHexRGBAString:@"#0288D1"] CGColor];

    _user_profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = _user_profileImage.frame.size.height /2;
    _user_profileImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    _user_profileImage.layer.borderWidth = 0;


    _view1.alpha=0.5;
    _view1.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
    _view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];

    _view2.alpha=0.5;
    _view2.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
    _view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];


    _view3.alpha=0.5;
    _view3.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
    _view3.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];


    _view4.alpha=0.5;
    _view4.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
    _view4.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];

    _view5.alpha=0.5;
    _view5.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
    _view5.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];


    NSInteger open =  [globalVariables.OpenCount integerValue];
    NSInteger closed = [globalVariables.ClosedCount integerValue];
    NSInteger trash = [globalVariables.DeletedCount integerValue];
    NSInteger unasigned = [globalVariables.UnassignedCount integerValue];
    NSInteger my_tickets = [globalVariables.MyticketsCount integerValue];

    if(open>99){
        _c1.text=@"99+";
    }else
        _c1.text=@(open).stringValue;
    if(closed>99){
        _c4.text=@"99+";
    }else
        _c4.text=@(closed).stringValue;
    if(trash>99){
        _c5.text=@"99+";
    }else
        _c5.text=@(trash).stringValue;
    if(unasigned>99){
        _c3.text=@"99+";
    }else
        _c3.text=@(unasigned).stringValue;
    if(my_tickets>99){
        _c2.text=@"99+";
    }else
        _c2.text=@(my_tickets).stringValue;

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

and add this code,

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

 [self.tableView reloadData];
    //[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

and call getDependencies method in viewDidLoad method.
check it once and let me know..!

Comment: i checked but....sometimes it load and sometimes or not...! I am calling getDependencies method from viewWillAppear, so I can load data before it appear, I mean getDependencies method called and values will update..! is it right ?

Comment: call getDependencies in viewDidLoad and here also call update method..! Dont call getDependencies in viewWillAppear method...! and use [self.tableView reloadData]; method reload a tableview...! It will work..!

Answer (score 0):

You can create `IBOutlet` for all labels which needs to be updated. Instead of reloading tableview on updating count you can update the count any where in your controller class. You can move all the code related to updating count in separate method and call this method whenever its required.

```
 func updateAllLabels() {
    NSInteger open =  [globalVariables.OpenCount integerValue];
    NSInteger closed = [globalVariables.ClosedCount integerValue];
    NSInteger trash = [globalVariables.DeletedCount integerValue];
    NSInteger unasigned = [globalVariables.UnassignedCount integerValue];
    NSInteger my_tickets = [globalVariables.MyticketsCount integerValue];

    if(open>999){
        _inbox_countLabel.text=@"999+";
    }else
        _inbox_countLabel.text=@(open).stringValue;
    if(closed>999){
        _closed_countLabel.text=@"999+";
    }else
        _closed_countLabel.text=@(closed).stringValue;
    if(trash>999){
        _trash_countLabel.text=@"999+";
    }else
        _trash_countLabel.text=@(trash).stringValue;
    if(unasigned>999){
        _unassigned_countLabel.text=@"999+";
    }else
        _unassigned_countLabel.text=@(unasigned).stringValue;
    if(my_tickets>999){
        _myTickets_countLabel.text=@"999+";
    }else
        _myTickets_countLabel.text=@(my_tickets).stringValue;
}
```

And call this `updateAllLabels` method when values get update. If you are aware that only one value will get update you can update that label only.